# c/c++ what is the return value of strncmp when size is 0

Tags: c++, c, size, strncmp

The c/c++ strncmp signature is like the following:

```
int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num );
```

My question is what's the return value if num is 0?  How the standard says? Don't find an answer from some online documents.

Thanks.

Comment: Logically it should be 0, since there's no way for one of the strings to be greater or less than the other.

Comment: You could always [try it and see](http://ideone.com/4e4frw).

Answer (score 8):

Well, `strncmp` compares at most `num` characters from the two strings, so with `num == 0`, it compares none, hence finds no difference, thus it returns 0.

Comment: But that makes no sense. returns 0 means the two string are identical. actually there are not. If that's the standard says, then i think it is a bug in  the standard. No matter what returns 0 or 1, it is not a reasonable value, I think.

Comment: @nowgainsnowpains: A string containing zero characters is identical to another string containing zero characters.

Comment: @nowgainsnowpains Although returning 0 from `strcmp` means that the strings are equal, this does not hold for `strncmp`. For that function, returning 0 means that the substrings of the first `n` characters are equal. Passing zero for `n` effectively means comparing two empty strings, which are indeed equal to each other.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Fair explaination. Thanks.

Comment: @nowgainsnowpains `strncmp` compares initial parts of two strings, and returns 0, a positive value or a negative value if the prefix of length `num` of the first string is equal to, greater or smaller than the prefix of length `num` of the second string. The prefix of length 0 of any string is an empty string, so all prefixes of length 0 are equal.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight even a more reasonable explaination. Thanks.

Comment: Another way to think of it: imagine `strncmp(a, b, n)`, logically, as first taking `strndup(a, n)` and `strndup(b, n)` and then passing the results to `strcmp`.

Comment: @R.. I believe that both the answer and your comment are valid iff the passed pointers are `!= NULL` otherwise the behavior is undefined, instead.